# It gives me an error in remix. I have no idea why! Can you guys please help?

Tags: solidity, remix, error, solidity-0.8.x

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;

interface ERC20Interface {
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) external view returns (uint balance);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) external view returns (uint remaining);
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
}

contract ERC20Token is ERC20Interface {
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals;
    uint public totalSupply;
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) public allowed;
    
    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        uint8 _decimals,
        uint _totalSupply)
        public {
            name = _name;
            symbol = _symbol;
            decimals = _decimals;
            totalSupply = _totalSupply;
            balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;
        }
        
    function transfer(address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= value);
        balances[msg.sender] -= value;
        balances[to] += value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }
    
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        uint allowance = allowed[from][msg.sender];
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= value && allowance >= value);
        allowed[from][msg.sender] -= value;
        balances[msg.sender] -= value;
        balances[to] += value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }
    
    function approve(address spender, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        require(spender != msg.sender);
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
        return true;
    }
    
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view returns(uint) {
        return allowed[owner][spender];
    }
    
    function balanceOf(address owner) public view returns(uint) {
        return balances[owner];
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You are re-implementing the functions of parent contracts thus solidity is asking you to `override` those functions.

Comment: Do I need to use the word virtual with override? Should I use override in the interface or in the contract itself? *It does not work on totalSupply getter function!

Comment: You should add virtual keyword to function defination of ERC20 contract. You also need to add override to totalSupply variable in ERC20Token since it creates getter function automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
contract ERC20Token is ERC20Interface {
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals;
    uint public override totalSupply;
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) public allowed;

    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        uint8 _decimals,
        uint _totalSupply)
    public {
        name = _name;
        symbol = _symbol;
        decimals = _decimals;
        totalSupply = _totalSupply;
        balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;
    }
        
    function transfer(address to, uint value) public override returns(bool) {
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= value);
        balances[msg.sender] -= value;
        balances[to] += value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }
    
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public override returns(bool) {
        uint allowance = allowed[from][msg.sender];
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= value && allowance >= value);
        allowed[from][msg.sender] -= value;
        balances[msg.sender] -= value;
        balances[to] += value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }
    
    function approve(address spender, uint value) public override returns(bool) {
        require(spender != msg.sender);
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
        return true;
    }
    
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public override view returns(uint) {
        return allowed[owner][spender];
    }
    
    function balanceOf(address owner) public override view returns(uint) {
        return balances[owner];
    }
    
}
```

Implementation for @Emrah 's answer